Autologin in GDM Gnome disable terminal and nautilus
I have configured an Oracle Linux (Oracle Linux Server release 9.4 Unbreakable Kernel) with graphical interface (systemctl set-default graphical).
I have configured a TigerVNC server to access remotely in graphical mode.
I want to connect using the VNC password, but avoid the login GDM screen (I want to ensure that autostart graphical programs start without need of login). For this, I edited the configuration with sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf and added the lines
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=myuser

With this, it seems to work fine (I can connect and see desktop with no problem), but I get a strange behaviour. The gnome programs, as gnome-terminal or nautilus (and other) does not start. For get it starting, I have to do with sudo from terminal.
Other programs start fine (from desktop or terminal)
If I disable the AutomaticLogin all returns to normal, but the autostart programs wait for my login!
Any suggestion will be welcome.
